# Python Code Momentarily Working only when pyc files change

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyc

I'm experiencing a very odd issue. I've changed a bit of python code from one revision to the next and it seemed to break the code (despite passing tests). When I went and added a debug statement, the code began working fine. Trying it again made it fail. After experimenting, I realized that it would work on one run only after the pyc file was changed or deleted. What?? Has anyone else experienced this? Any ideas to fix this?

tldr: Code only works right after pyc changed or deleted and then stops working.

EDIT: It seems to be the issue is the pyc file by itself. I compiled the pyc files without running the code and tried running it and it didn't work. 
I did some research and I THINK that the way python creates these pyc is that when I try to run it, it loads it into the environment and then creates the pyc. Which means that it works when it's loaded in from source, but fails when loaded in from pyc.

Comment: does your program have side effect which outlive the process? files, FS-locks, DB updates? Are you running locally, or are any of the files on a remote/network drive?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any side effect. I'm running through an ssh terminal.

Comment: As an update, I never found a satisfactory solution. All I'm doing now is not generating the pyc file. My application imports everything once at the beginning and runs in the background so this isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps your PYC file is being updated by some sort of sync, written after its been compiled, then python runs the PYC instead of recompiling the PY.

Try this:

```
>python --help
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sync, but there does seem to be something wrong with the pyc, as per my edit above.

Comment: sync for synchronization such as rsync, or a cloud storage updating the file. Maybe CVS? Delete the pyc file then run python with -B and ensure its not created. If it is then its created from somewhere else (heaven maybe?)

Comment: When I add in -B the pyc is not created and program works fine. Though I don't know if adding -B is a long term solution.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could be a bug, try updating python if that is possible. Or could be something filesystem related. Try moving the python file to another disk, or another foler, etc. Also try reproducint and check modified date on pyc and if its after you last ran the .py